# SMTP email sending not works for in docker compse

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I have set the STMP email configuration in my docker-compose.yml file.

```
environment:
    DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL: test@company.com
    EMAIL_HOST: smtp.office365.com
    EMAIL_PORT: 25
    EMAIL_HOST_USER: test@company.com
    EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD: Aald1231w
    EMAIL_USE_TLS: 'True'
    EMAIL_USE_SSL: 'True'
```

I'm getting the following error while trying to send mail using the docker exec command,

```
docker exec -it kiwi_web /Kiwi/manage.py sendtestemail test@company.com
```

Error:

```
docker exec -it kiwi_web /Kiwi/manage.py sendtestemail test@company.com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Kiwi/manage.py", line 12, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/sendtestemail.py", line 33, in handle
    recipient_list=kwargs['email'],
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 61, in send_mail
    return mail.send()
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 284, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 102, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 62, in open
    self.connection = self.connection_class(self.host, self.port, **connection_params)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 336, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 307, in _get_socket
    self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/socket.py", line 724, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/socket.py", line 713, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
```

Could you please tell what I'm doing wrong here?, I have used the same configuration to send mails, also tried this config in online SMTP tools. These settings are fine.

Note: while I try to use, following line without single quotes, get the error "services.web.environment.EMAIL_USE_TLS contains true, which is an invalid type, it should be a string, number, or a null". So used a single quote here.

```
   EMAIL_USE_TLS: 'True'
   EMAIL_USE_SSL: 'True'
```

Answer (score 0):

> Could you please tell what I'm doing wrong here?,

You are configuring your email settings as environment variable while Kiwi TCMS reads them from a config file which doesn't care what the external environment is. For how to override this file see:
https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing_docker.html#customization